# Maven to OBR Repositories

Tags: maven, osgi, obr

Since Maven cannot guarantee that a jar is also a bundle I want to use OBR as my project Repository. Of course in case of OSGi it has a lot of more nice features why I am using it :) So, are there possibilities to add jars published to a Maven Repository to an OBR Repository or could I simply add a whole Maven Repo to it? Or is it possible to address a Maven URL directly in you OBR metadata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Maven Bundle Plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) to add OBR metadata to your repository when deploying.

This plugin will add OBR metadata to any plugin you deploy.

I also think Nexus Open Source has support for OBR now, but I'm not entirely sure.

Finally, the [PAX URL](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxurl/Pax+URL) library might be of use to you. Using this library you can use maven style urls that Pax will resolve for you (e.g. 'mvn:groupid/artifactId')

regards, Frank

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to use a repository manager and add the appropriate repository to the configuration of the repo manager. Furthmore it's possible to add a repository within your settings.xml file as a supplemental resources.